# Iterate Through rows in Excel

Tags: c#, excel

I am attempting to get all the numbers from the cells in column A from an excel spreadsheet, but I am only getting my header line returned. What am I doing wrong?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Documents\ANIs.xlsx");
    Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[1];

    Range a1 = worksheet.get_Range("$A1");

    object rawValue = a1.Value;
    string Text = a1.Text;

    foreach (Range item in a1.Cells)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{1}", rawValue, Text);    
    }
    Console.Read();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting only the cell A1, you can get all the cells in column A by using :

```
Range firstCol = workSheet.Range("A:A");
```

Comment: Since excel is now 1M cell wide I recommend to set a reasonable end like `"A:A1000"` to avoid browsing a lot of empty cells

Answer (score 0):

Because your worksheet.get_Range is only returning the one cell. You need to specify the lower-right cell also to get multiple cells, like this:

```
worksheet.get_Range("$A1", "$D9");
```

Check out [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.get_range(v=vs.120).aspx)

Comment: I tried adding     '("A:A");' and     '("$A1", "$D9")' and got errors both times saying that Numbers does not exist in the current context.  with my 'string Text = a1.Text' highlighted.

Comment: @MrASifuMason that would indicate the problem is with the underlying value that is in your Range object a1. If you are expanding the object to contain more than one cell, there are probably other values in the object that are unable to be coerced to a string. Set a break point on that line and check out the a1 object. You will probably need reference a specific cell within the range object a1 something like this:         `a1("A1:B2")(1)` refers to cell A1 
`a1("A1:B2")(2)` refers to cell B1

Comment: And now I have "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DBNull' to 'srtring' on that string Text line.

Comment: That's true, any null cannot be converted to a string type. There are many ways to deal with that, try using null coalescing: `String Text = a1("A1:B2")(1) ?? "IAmNull";`

Comment: When I tried that it gave me "Cannot invoke a non-delegate type"

Comment: We're getting off-topic now. That sounds like it could just be a typo or syntax error. I'd suggest starting another question with a new topic for the new error message. But you might try Ternery: `String Text = a1("A1:B2")(1) != null ? a1("A1:B2")(1) : "IAmNull";` or use the `if String.IsNullOrEmpty(a1("A1:B2")(1))`